# Using apx/gateway package with aws localstack

Tags: go, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, localstack

I'm using localstack to deploy a lambda function written in Go, and I'm using `apex/gateway` package to implement this. Basically this package is a drop-in replacement for net/http's ListenAndServe for use in AWS Lambda.
Here is my Go source code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/apex/gateway"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", hello)
    log.Fatal(gateway.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil))
}

func hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // example retrieving values from the api gateway proxy request context.
    requestContext, ok := gateway.RequestContext(r.Context())
    if !ok || requestContext.Authorizer["sub"] == nil {
        fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello World from Go")
        return
    }

    userID := requestContext.Authorizer["sub"].(string)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello %s from Go", userID)
}
```

This is the list of commands I used to deploy this Golang source code into localstack lambda.

```
GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o main main.go
zip -D main.zip main
awslocal lambda create-function --function-name main --zip-file fileb://main.zip --runtime go1.x --role arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/lambda-role
awslocal lambda invoke --function-name main output.txt
```

Then it prints out the following into terminal.

```
{
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "ExecutedVersion": "$LATEST"
}
```

and prints out the following into output.txt file.

```
{"statusCode":301,"headers":{"Content-Type":"text/html; charset=utf-8","Location":"/"},"multiValueHeaders":{},"body":"\u003ca href=\"/\"\u003eMoved Permanently\u003c/a\u003e.\n\n"}
```

I think it's supposed to print out "Hello World from Go"

I found the similar post here [Porting a golang server app to aws lambda + api gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64555096/porting-a-golang-server-app-to-aws-lambda-api-gateway) but I wasn't get any help.

Comment: Hello, is this issue here the 301? Can you deploy this to AWS and see if this still persists? If so, something is wrong with your application. The key here is to narrow down the problem radius as much as possible. Also you're just invoking the Lambda without calling it via an API gateway route that would trigger '/'. Is there an API gateway here or not? And if not, then what is `http.HandleFunc("/", hello)` for?